# openvpn routing setup for incoming connections on client

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have a debian server, call it A, that is connected as an openvpn client to another network. Server A is also http and email server accepting connections from the internet. Now, one of the servers on the other network, call it B, is connecting to A over the internet; email and http. However those connections fail (timeout) as long as the routing setup on A is to route connections to B via the VPN tunnel.

My guess is that I need some kind of setup that will route replies to incoming connections from B over the internet instead of over the VPN tunnel.

This is the routing table on A:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
<snip>
B               VPN server      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Who set that metric of 100 for the default route?

Comment: Although old question - Would really like to know an answer. Have exact same situation

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not writing a comment, but my rep is too low for that. 
Is the connection from B to A to the http, or email service coming through the VPN or through the internet?

If it's coming through the internet, you could bind the outgoing ip address in the services to the external interface

For postfix p.e. with

```
smtp_bind_address = [external ip address]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The connection is coming through the internet.